# Android Kotlin: Convert from java (wrong arguments?)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to convert Java code to Kotlin. But that doesn't work. ArrayAdapter cannot inherit because an error is thrown: "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied." Strangely enough, it does not recognize getApplicationContext () either, although I am not sure whether it is a consequential error.

Kotlin-Trial:

```
package com.example.evpic.ui.main


import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.annotation.Nullable
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.example.evpic.R
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import java.io.*
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL


class LoginSucessActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var listView: ListView? = null
    var sTitle =
        arrayOf("Facebook", "Whatsapp", "Twitter", "Instagram", "Youtube")
    var mDescription = arrayOf(
        "Facebook Description",
        "Whatsapp Description",
        "Twitter Description",
        "Instagram Description",
        "Youtube Description"
    )
    var images = arrayOf(
        R.drawable.o_one,
        R.drawable.o_one,
        R.drawable.o_one,
        R.drawable.o_one,
        R.drawable.o_one
    )

    val PICK_IMAGE = 1 //

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.w("xxxxxxxxxxx", "LoginSucessActivity");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
    }


    internal class MyAdapater : ArrayAdapter<String>() constructor(c_: Context,  title_: Array<String>,  description_: Array<String>, imgs_: Array<Int>) : super(c_, R.layout.row, R.id.textView1, title_) {
        var c: Context? = null
        var rTitle: Array<String>? = null
        var rDescription: Array<String>? = null
        var rImgs: Array<Int>? = null
        constructor  {
            c = c_
            rTitle = title_
            rDescription = description_
            rImgs = imgs_
        }


        override fun getView(position: Int, @Nullable convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater =  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater


            val row: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false)
            val images: ImageView = row.findViewById(R.id.image)
            val myTitle = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)
            val myDescription = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)


            images.setImageResource(rImgs!![position])
            myTitle.text = rTitle!![position]
            myDescription.text = rDescription!![position]

            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
        }

    }

}
```

Original Java-Code:

```
class MyAdapater extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    Context context;
    String sTitle[];
    String rDescription[];
    int rImgs[];

    MyAdapter(Context c, String title[], String description[], int imgs[]){
        super(c, R.layout.row, R.id.textView1, title);
        this.context = c;
        this.rTitle = title;
        this.rDescription = description;
        this.rImgs = imgs;
    }
        
        
        
    @NonNull
    @OVerride
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflator)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        ImageView images = row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView myTitle = row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView myDescription = row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        images.setImageResource(rImgs[position]);
        myTitle.setText(rTitle[position]);
        myDescription.setText(rDescription[position]);

        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Did you convert this to Kotlin by hand or by using using the built in tool to convert to Kotlin?

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` in Kotlin is `applicationContext`

Comment: What is the point of the secondary constructor? It fails to call any super constructor and the whole class would be useless if the Context is nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code of the `MyAdapater` class should be:

```
internal class MyAdapter constructor(
        val c: Context,
        val title: Array<String>,
        val description: Array<String>,
        val imgs: Array<Int>
) : ArrayAdapter<String>(c, R.layout.row, R.id.textView1, title) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater =  c.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

        val row: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false)
        val images = row.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
        val myTitle = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)
        val myDescription = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)

        images.setImageResource(imgs[position])
        myTitle.text = title[position]
        myDescription.text = description[position]

        return row
    }
}
```